libzip functions return success but do nothing
[EDIT] I discovered a couple things that have gotten me past this issue by stepping through the library source in my debugger.

The zip_open() function does not actually create a file, it just saves the name for later use by zip_close().  If the current directory was changed during processing and not restored before calling zip_close(), then the ZIP file will be created in whatever directly was last set as current.  IMHO, this is a bug in the library -- if there was no path given in the zip_open() call, the current directory should be prepended onto the saved ZIP file name for later (correct) use by zip_close().
I have had much better luck by removing drive letters and leaving backslashes from all folder and file names, except for the filename passed to zip_source_file(), which needs to know the fully qualified path.  But zip_file_add() seemed to work better without a C:\ (or whatever) at the beginning of the file's mostly qualified name.

[OP] I'm trying to learn how to use libzip to create a ZIP file with Visual Studio 2022 and C on Windows 11.  When I'm finished, my file should have multiple files in multiple different folders.  That's my final goal.  Right now, I just want to create a ZIP file, but the library is not helping me to use it correctly because it is not returning errors, even when it fails to do anything (detectable) that I've asked it to do.  I'm not looking for help fixing my code (though I certainly won't refuse it! [smile]), what I'm really trying to learn here is how to debug problems with a library that returns success even when it clearly fails.
If I just use this basic sequence (with _UseFqn_ defined), with fully qualified path/file names (fqn), then a ZIP is actually created (Windows won't read it, but 7-Zip will, so that's OK for now):
zip_open()
zip_source_file(fqn)
zip_file_add(fqn)
zip_close()

If I use SetCurrentDirectory() to change to the folder that actually contains each file (fpath), and try to add the files without path information (fname), then I get no errors but I also get no zip file:
zip_open()
SetCurrentDirectory(fpath)
zip_source_file(fname)
zip_file_add(fname)
zip_close()

If I try to add a directory using zip_dir_add(), I also get no errors and no zip file for either of the sequences above.  Sorry for the length of this post, but I'm going to add my test source, too.  Please make one assumption about it:  The program calling _MakeZipFile() is calling it like this:  _MakeZipFile("testfile.zip","C:\path\to\file\something.log\0");
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Add a single file to the zip
static int _AddFileToZip( zip_t *zipFile, char *szFileName )
{
   int            rc = NO_ERROR;
   zip_source_t  *source;

   source = zip_source_file( zipFile, szFileName, 0, ZIP_LENGTH_TO_END );
   if( source == NULL )
   {
      printf( "ZipTest>  Failed to src file for zip:  '%s'...\n", szFileName );
      printf( "ZipTest>  libzip:  %s\n", zip_strerror( zipFile ) );
      rc = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
   }
   else if( zip_file_add( zipFile, szFileName, source, ZIP_FL_ENC_RAW ) < 0 )
   {
      zip_source_free( source );
      printf( "ZipTest>  Failed to add file to zip:  '%s'...\n", szFileName );
      printf( "ZipTest>  libzip:  %s\n", zip_strerror( zipFile ) );
      rc = ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
   }
   else
   {  // print a diagnostic for debugging
      printf( "ZipTest>  added file:  '%s'...\n", szFileName );
   }
   return rc;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Add all folder levels, from top to bottom, recursively
static BOOL _AddFolderToZip( zip_t *zipFile, char *szFolder )
{
   char         sz[_MAX_PATH];
   char        *cp;
   BOOL         bResult;
   zip_error_t *pze;

   if( ':' == szFolder[1] )
   {  // Remove drive letter, if present
      szFolder += 2;
   }
   if( '\\' == *szFolder )
   {  // Remove leading backslash, if present
      szFolder++;
   }
   
   strcpy( sz, szFolder ); // copy so we don't trash the original
   cp = strrchr( sz, '\\' );
   if( cp && ('\0' == *(cp+1)) )
   {  // Remove trailing backslash
      *cp = '\0';
   }

   // Is this a sub-folder?
   cp = strrchr( sz, '\\' );
   if( cp && (cp != sz) )
   {  // Yes, call self to add parent first
      *cp = '\0';
      if( !_AddFolderToZip( zipFile, sz ) )
      {  // Failure, back out with errors
         return FALSE;
      }
      *cp = '\\';
   }

   // else No, time to add this folder.
   bResult = TRUE;
   if( zip_dir_add( zipFile, sz, ZIP_FL_ENC_RAW ) < 0 )
   {  // Error, but there's one error that is OK...
      pze = zip_get_error( zipFile );
      if( ZIP_ER_EXISTS != pze->zip_err )
      {  // Multiple files in same folder are OK.
         bResult = FALSE;
         printf( "ZipTest>  Failed to add directory to zip:  '%s'...\n", szFolder );
         printf( "ZipTest>  libzip:  %s\n", zip_strerror( zipFile ) );
      }
   }
   if( bResult )
   {  // print a diagnostic for debugging
      printf( "ZipTest>  added directory:  '%s'...\n", sz );
   }
   return bResult;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define _UseFqn_ 1   // Use Fully qualified file names and no directories
// comment this out to change directory, add the file folder, and add the filename
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

// szzSourceList is a buffoer containing some number of NULL terminated
//               strings that ends with an empty string (i.e. double-NULL)
BOOL _MakeZipFile( char *szZipFileName, char *szzSourceList )
{
   BOOL              result = FALSE;
   int               errorp = NO_ERROR;
   zip_t            *zipFile;
   char             *cpFilePath;
   zip_error_t       ziperror;
   zip_error_t      *pze;
#if !defined(_UseFqn_)
   char              szDrive[_MAX_PATH];
   char              szPath[_MAX_PATH];
   char              szFile[_MAX_PATH];
   char              szExt[_MAX_PATH];
   char              szFolder[_MAX_PATH];
#endif
   char              szStartPath[_MAX_PATH];

   GetCurrentDirectory( sizeof(szStartPath), szStartPath );

   zipFile = zip_open( szZipFileName, ZIP_CREATE | ZIP_TRUNCATE, &errorp );
   if( zipFile == NULL )
   {
      zip_error_init_with_code( &ziperror, errorp );
      printf( "ZipTest>  Failed to open output file '%s'...\n", szZipFileName );
      printf( "ZipTest>  libzip:  %s\n", zip_error_strerror( &ziperror ) );
      return FALSE;
   }

   __try
   {
      cpFilePath = szzSourceList;
      while( *cpFilePath )
      {
#if defined(_UseFqn_)
         _AddFileToZip( zipFile, cpFilePath );
#else
         _splitpath( cpFilePath, szDrive, szPath, szFile, szExt );
         sprintf( szFolder, "%s%s", szDrive, szPath );
         SetCurrentDirectory( szFolder );
         _AddFolderToZip( zipFile, szPath );
         strcat( szFile, szExt );
         _AddFileToZip( zipFile, szFile );
#endif

         // Find next entry in \0\0 terminated string list
         while( *cpFilePath )
         {
            cpFilePath++;
         }
         cpFilePath++;
      }
   }
   __finally
   {
      if( NO_ERROR == zip_close( zipFile ) )
      {
         result = TRUE;
      }
      else
      {
         pze = zip_get_error( zipFile );
         printf( "ZipTest>  Failed to create output file '%s'...\n", szZipFileName );
         printf( "ZipTest>  libzip:  %s\n", zip_strerror( zipFile ) );
         printf( "ZipTest>  zip_err = %d   sys_err = %d\n", pze->zip_err, pze->sys_err );
      }
   }

   SetCurrentDirectory( szStartPath );

   return result;
}


This question would be easier to answer if it was written so others could reproduce it. I can't reproduce the problem because there's no MRE. I tried expanding the pseudocode in your second example into something that runs on my machine, but I can see that zip_close() fails with the streerror message: "Read error: No such file or directory".

I noticed that zip_file_add() and zip_source_file() return a success error code even if their "name" argument is not a path to a real file. That behavior was surprising to me, and I'd understand that this is frustrating if you expect that to be communicated as a failure.
To answer your question directly:

how to debug problems with a library that returns success even when it clearly fails

If one thinks that a library function "clearly fails" but it is returning a success code, then I'd say there are two possibilities:

There is a bug in the library code.
Your expectations for what "success" and "fail" in this context mean something different than the library author's expectations.

And the great thing about using an open source library is that (in theory) you can check for case 1 yourself.
Judging from the documented errors and the source code, I think that the developers don't consider it a failure mode when the "fname" argument does not point to a file.
You can even send a patch to the authors to update the docs to make it clearer.  And it seems like they're active so it might get fixed.
For the problem with your function, I would try to test if the file exists and is readable (you can use fopen(fname, "r") for this) before trying to add it to the archive with zip_source_file().

Thanks, if (when?) I think I understand it well enough, I will likely suggest documentation improvements.  At least I got it working by no longer changing directory, and removing the leading drive\ from file names added to the ZIP.
